# In GANs, why converging the discriminator to probability 0.5 does not make the generator to change its good learned weights?

Tags: gan

It is said that the discriminator part of GANs converges to probability 0.5, meaning that when it gets an instance generated by generator, it says that it is a fake instance by probability equal to 0.5. I expect that it says it is a real image (i.e., the probability of being fake is zero). Otherwise, the generator tries to change its learned weights to fool the discriminator, and it would destroy the generator. What is wrong with my explanations?

Comment: Why would this destroy anything? The generator should be updated so that it's outputs more closely mimic the true distribution of images. Nothing is destroyed.

Comment: @shimao Thanks for your comment. The generator tries to minimize $log(1-D(G(z)))$, so the optimal point is where $D(G(Z))=1$, where $D(x)$ is the probability that $x$ came from true distribution. $D(G(Z))=0.5$ means that generator is not good enough, so it should change its weights to generate more realistic samples.